# How to extract all three (five) digits from the string using regular expressions?

Tags: r, regex

I have a string value, say, `102-105+106-10605-10605 -10610-10610+10613`. How can extract easily all values of three digits, all values of five digits. An additional task is to take into account the `+ or -`  signs before the values. Say, extract all  values of 5 digits that have sign `-` before.

I know that there are some packages in R that enable you to do that. But I don't know how to do that exactly. I've tried various code, but unfortunately I failed each time.

From the vector I've mentioned  I would like to extract all values of three digits and only five digits.

I used the code

```
str_extract_all(d, ("\\d{3}"))
```

And it gives me

```
[1] "102" "105" "106" "106" "106" "106" "106" "106" "106" "106".
```

But I want the following result `"102" "105" "106"`. i.e. the code should not take into acconts 5-digits values and extract from them any three digits in a row.

In case of 5-digits query `str_extract_all(d, ("\\d{5}"))` it gives me

```
[1] "10605" "10605" "10610" "10610" "10613" "10613" "10620".
```

This result is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like this...

```
library(stringr)
d<-"102-105+106-10605-10605 -10610-10610+10613"

str_match_all(d, "\\b([\\+\\-]*\\d{3})\\b")[[1]][,2]
[1] "102"  "-105" "+106"

str_match_all(d, "\\b([\\+\\-]*\\d{5})\\b")[[1]][,2]
[1] "-10605" "-10605" "10610"  "-10610" "+10613"
```

Delete the `[\\+\\-]*` if you don't want to capture the leading `+/-`.

The `\\b` is regex for a "word boundary" - the start or end of a word (or, in this case, number).

Answer (score 0):

```
vect <- "102-105+106-10605-10605 -10610-10610+10613"

#Extract 3 digits
str_extract_all(vect, pattern = "[:digit:]{3}")
[[1]]
[1] "102" "105" "106" "106" "106" "106" "106" "106"

#Extract 5 digits    
str_extract_all(vect, pattern = "[:digit:]{5}")
[[1]]
[1] "10605" "10605" "10610" "10610" "10613"

#Extract 5 digits with minus sign ahead of it
str_extract_all(vect, pattern = "-[:digit:]{5}")
[[1]]
[1] "-10605" "-10605" "-10610" "-10610"
```

Hope this helps
For reference:
https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html

Edit: *based on your comment*

```
vect2 <- str_split(vect, pattern = "[^[:alnum:]]")
vect2
[[1]]
[1] "102"   "105"   "106"   "10605" "10605" ""      "10610" "10610" "10613"

unlist(str_extract_all(unlist(vect2), pattern = "^[:digit:]{3}$"))
[1] "102" "105" "106"
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need to escape value if it has more then 3 digits (in case of three digits) and escape all values that have less or more 5 digits. I.e. as a resultof three digits query I would like to get '102' '105' '106'. In case of 5 digits '10605' '10605' '10610' etc. Thans you

Comment: I think it has to be split like above edit, otherwise it'll always consider either the first three or last three of the 5 digit numbers

Comment: Unfortunately it gives a little bit another result then I want. That's because the example I've provided with is not perfect. I'll try one more time. Suppose we have the next vector `102-105+106-10705-10805 -10910-11010+11113`. As a result of the 3-digit's request  it should list me only `102, 105, 106`. But you code provides the `107` as well if we run your code on the vector wich is not waht I want. I hope I described well.

Comment: It doesn't provide the 107.   
vect3 <- "102-105+106-10705-10805 -10910-11010+11113"  
vect4 <- str_split(vect3, pattern = "[^[:alnum:]]")  
unlist(str_extract_all(unlist(vect4), pattern = "^[:digit:]{3}$"))
[1] "102" "105" "106"